# Filter entities with tags - Symfony2 & FPNTagBundle

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, tags, query-builder

I have entities Site which are taggable.
I use [FPNTagBundle](https://github.com/FabienPennequin/FPNTagBundle) for the tagging feature.

The problem is do not manage to query my site entities with a tag filter.

Those two entities (sites and tags) do not have a multiple relation.

I am trying that kind of things:

```
$qb->select('site')
->from('OctopoluxScoutBundle:Site', 'site')
->innerJoin('FPN\TagBundle\Entity\Tagging', 't2', 'WITH', 't2.resourceId = :id AND t2.resourceType = :type')
 ->setParameter('id', 'site.id')
 ->setParameter('type', 'site')
 ->orderBy('site.published', 'DESC')
 ->setMaxResults($limit)
 ->setFirstResult($offset);

$result=$qb->getQuery()->getResult();
return $result;
```

It seems i am pretty close but it returns an exception

```
Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'scout.fpn_tag_tagging' doesn't exist
```

The thing is the concerned table is called tagging but in the XML definition of the tagging entity, I read

```
<mapped-superclass name="FPN\TagBundle\Entity\Tagging" table="fpn_tag_tagging">
```

I am sure I am not far from the solution but I am struggling with it.

Any help would be much appreciated.
Thank you

Comment: you need to update you database schema with `php app/console doctrine:schema:update --force` or --dump-sql to dump the query to execute

Comment: Hello. It is not the problem. I can tag en retrieve tags. The problem is that I can not filter on tags.

Comment: the exception says that table fpn_tag_tagging don't exists, and you need it